# ASP.NET MVC After Post Back List that contains List property in ViewModel is null

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

As I mentioned in title after Post Back List (MySalonTreatments) property in ViewModel is null.

I am new to MVC but I think it should work. Model binder know how to handle complex types.
I search a lot but I do not get on any solution. Maybe you could point me errors.

ViewModel:

```
public class CreateSalonViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

    //it shouldn't be facebook adress
    public string Website { get; set; }

    public string MobilePhone { get; set; }

    public string LandlinePhone { get; set; }

    public int CityId { get; set; }

    public int ProvinceId { get; set; }

    public List<SalonTreatments> MySalonTreatments;
}

public class SalonTreatments
{
    public List<Treatment> SpecTypeTreaments { get; set; }
    public TreatmentType TreatmentType { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class SalonController : Controller
{
    private CrsDatabase db = new CrsDatabase();

    //
    // GET: /Salon/Create
    [Authorize]
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View(GetCreateSalonViewModel());
    }

    [Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(CreateSalonViewModel createSalonViewModel)
    {
        return View(createSalonViewModel);
    }

    #region service methods

    private CreateSalonViewModel GetCreateSalonViewModel()
    {
        CreateSalonViewModel createSalonViewModel = new CreateSalonViewModel();
        createSalonViewModel.MySalonTreatments = new List<SalonTreatments>();

        foreach (var treatmentType in db.TreatmentType)
        {
            var treatmentOfSpecType = db.Treatment.Where(t => t.TreatmentType.Id == treatmentType.Id).ToList();
            if (treatmentOfSpecType.Count > 0)
            {
                SalonTreatments salonTreatments = new SalonTreatments();
                salonTreatments.TreatmentType = treatmentType;
                salonTreatments.SpecTypeTreaments = treatmentOfSpecType;

                createSalonViewModel.MySalonTreatments.Add(salonTreatments);
            }
        }

        return createSalonViewModel;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

View:

```
@model CRSWebsite.ViewModels.CreateSalonViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Salon", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>CreateSalonViewModel</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmailAddress, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmailAddress)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmailAddress)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Website, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Website)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Website)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MobilePhone, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MobilePhone)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MobilePhone)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LandlinePhone, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LandlinePhone)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LandlinePhone)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CityId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CityId)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CityId)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProvinceId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProvinceId)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProvinceId)
            </div>
        </div>

        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.MySalonTreatments.Count; i++)
        {
            <label>Zabiegi @Model.MySalonTreatments[i].TreatmentType.Name:</label>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @for (int j = 0; j < Model.MySalonTreatments[i].SpecTypeTreaments.Count; j++)
                    {
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.MySalonTreatments[i].SpecTypeTreaments[j].IsSelected)
                        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.MySalonTreatments[i].SpecTypeTreaments[j].Name)
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        }
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Regards,
Peter

Comment: Wheres your POST action?

Comment: The fact that you used the words "post back" is an indication that you may be used to the Web Forms world where Viewstate existed.  Viewstate was trying to solve the stateless problem of the web which ASP.NET MVC doesn't do.

Comment: @JustinHelgerson: this is pretty obviously MVC code. "Postback" is a generic term that merely implies that the same URL that handled the GET is the also the one that handles the POST. The term is well-known in the Web Forms world because every page behaves this way, but it's not exclusive to Web Forms.

Comment: @PiotrLewicki: since the question is why your list is not populated on *POST*, why in the world would you *not* include your POST action?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I have resolved my issue!

It was trivial problem, in my viewmodel class CreateSalonViewModel I created treatments collection as:

```
public List<SalonTreatments> MySalonTreatments;
```

but for some unknown reason model binder can't handel this. Right way to do it is:

```
public List<SalonTreatments> MySalonTreatments { get; set; }
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: It's not an "unknown reason".  The model binder only works with public properties, you did not create a property, you created a field.

Comment: Ofcourse it was "unknown" only for me :-) I learned alot from this one!

Answer (score 1):

`public ActionResult Create()` appears to be the GET method for displaying your form.  You need another method to accept the POST, and make sure to add HttpGet to the first to ensure MVC can distinguish between the two.  Also verify your form is using the POSt method to submit the form:

```
[Authorize][HttpGet]
public ActionResult Create()
{
    return View(GetCreateSalonViewModel());
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(CreateSalonViewModel model) 
{  // MVC will try to bind your POSTed form to parameters
...
}
```